# Switch from consumer application to WCF (servicestack) by debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, wcf, servicestack

I am developing one product and there are 4 separate projects, in that I have developed one EXE project and WCF and I have done switching in debugging mode by attaching WCF project in process of debugging client of EXE and it has worked.

But when I transfer my WCF to servicestack then I could not able switch between them.

I am running my EXE project and and attached my WCF(servicestack) project to process

```
JsonServiceClient client = new JsonServiceClient("MYServiceURL");
RESTWCF.ServiceModel.Perfmon objBalPerformanceDataProperties = MakeObjectForServiceStackToInsertData();
var res = client.Post<RESTWCF.ServiceModel.Perfmon>("/perfmon", objBalPerformanceDataProperties);
```

When I click F11 on client.post I could not able to switch in WCF project, I think you can make sense of my problem.

Give me some solution of this problem so I can debug my code of WCF project (to find error :) in that)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only debug one host project at a time.

If you want to test the server set the ServiceStack project to be **Start-up Host** and press **F5** to start debugging the ServiceStack host. Put a break-point at the start of the service you want to hit.

You can then just **Run** (i.e. without debugging) the client application which if everything is configured correctly, it should hit your breakpoint.

To make sure you're debugging the service correctly, instead of running the client first try calling the web service via a url, e.g:

```
http://localhost/MyServiceUrl/perfmon
```

If it hits the break-point you set, then all is well and you can run the client application as mentioned above.

Also it's a good idea to include ServiceStack's debbuging symbols, i.e. it's *.pdb files in the same folder as it's *.dll's - as it helps with debugging.

Note: WCF has nothing to do with ServiceStack - In a lot of cases that's considered an insult :-)

Comment: Hello mythz my motive was not insult ServericeStack , that's great! :) just was clarifying my issue, thanks for your answer..

Comment: Yeah no worries :) just saw you mention WCF + ServiceStack in a couple of places so I just wanted to clarify it doesn't have anything to do with WCF. Except maybe that it was the reason I decided to start ServiceStack, because WCF was so bad :)

Comment: Oh that was my mistake, generally service & WCF mixed up in my talk, you guy is great thinker , who can think beyond WCF :) I have to learn many things from you.. thanks